# How do I actually create an account?

Tags: accounts

I want to get an actual dev account to create a cryptocurrency of my own, but I'm not even sure how to even make an account here.

https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/create-account.html

This link goes through how to make an account, yet it does so through Javascript and I'm not sure where you would actually write this code to do this.

Answer (score 4):

The first two JS examples are equivalent to the Lab tool here: https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#account-creator?network=test

Basically the first one generates your account keys (public and secret).

Then the second one sends an API request to the "Friendbot" who lives on the Testnet that gives you free Lumens to create the account. This is necessary because accounts are not considered "created" or "active" unless it has the minimum (1) amount of Lumens.

Answer (score 1):

> not sure where you would actually write this code to do this.

The code is written in JS. You may use [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/en/) to execute the JS code.

If you are rather new to programming, I assume it takes at least 2 hours to get you understanding what's going on. The laboratory is the best thing to start with to understand how Stellar's operations work.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the process of creating a cryptocurrency recently and I documented the steps that I took in a step by step fashion as opposed to the way the documentation explains it. Note, this is using the testnet and the Stellar Laboratory. You can do the same thing on the public network but it will cost some lumens to complete. Here are the steps they were taken in a form that makes sense to me:

```
CREATING THE ISSUER AND DISTRIBUTOR ACCOUNTS    
1. Google “Stellar Account Viewer”
2. Create two accounts - 1 as the issuer and 1 as the distributer
    1. Save the public and secret keys
3. Fund both accounts with 75 stellar lumens
4. Go to “Stellar Laboratory”

MARKING ISSUER AS TRUSTWORTHY
1. Go to the “Transaction Builder” Tab 
    1. Source account: DISTRIBUTING Account PUBLIC Key
    2. “Fetch the next…” button
    3. Operation Type: “Change Trust”
    4. Asset: “Alphanumeric 4”
        1. First field add the token symbol
        2. Second field add the ISSUING account PUBLIC Key
    5. Trust Limit: The amount of tokens you want to create
    6. “Sign In Transaction Signer” Button
    7. Add Signer: DISTRIBUTING account SECRET key
    8. “Sign with BIP Path” button - go to next step fast
    9. “Submit to Post Transaction endpoint” button - go to next step fast
    10. “Submit” button
    11. Wait for JSON response

ISSUING THE TOKEN
1. Go to the “Transaction Builder” Tab
    1. “Clear form contents and start over” button
    2. Source account: ISSUING Account PUBLIC Key
    3. “Fetch the next…” button
    4. Operation Type: “Payment”
    5. Destination: DISTRIBUTING account PUBLIC key
    6. Asset: “Alphanumeric 4”
        1. First field add the token symbol
        2. Second field add the ISSUING account PUBLIC Key
    7. Amount: Enter the amount of tokens to create (THIS IS CREATING THE TOKEN FROM AIR)
    8. “Sign In Transaction Signer” Button
    9. Add signer: ISSUING account SECRET KEY
    10. “Sign with BIP Path” button - go to next step fast
    11. “Submit to Post Transaction endpoint” button - go to next step fast
    12. “Submit” button
    13. Wait for JSON response

ENSURING THE TOKEN WAS CREATED
1. Go to “stellarterm.com/#markets” 
    1. Custom exchange (At the bottom)
        1. Asset Code: The token code created above
        2. Issuer Account ID or federation: ISSUING account PUBLIC key
        3. Counter Asset: XLM
        4. Custom token button (at the bottom)

REMOVING ABILITY TO CREATE MORE TOKENS
1. Go to the “Transaction Builder” Tab 
    1. “Clear form contents and start over” button
    2. Source account: ISSUING Account PUBLIC Key
    3. “Fetch the next…” button
    4. Operation Type: “Set Options”
    5. Master Weight: 0
    6. Low Threshold: 1
    7. Medium Threshold: 1
    8. High Threshold: 1
    9. Home Domain: domain that is hosting the stellar.toml file
    10. “Sign In Transaction Signer” Button
    11. Add signer: ISSUING account SECRET KEY
    12. “Sign with BIP Path” button - go to next step fast
    13. “Submit to Post Transaction endpoint” button - go to next step fast
    14. “Submit” button
    15. Wait for JSON response

ADDING THE TOKEN TO THE STELLAR EXCHANGE
1. Go to the “Transaction Builder” Tab 
    1. “Clear form contents and start over” button
    2. Source account: DISTRIBUTION Account PUBLIC Key
    3. “Fetch the next…” button
    4. Operation Type: “Manage Offer”
    5. Selling: “Alphanumeric 4”
        1. First field add the token symbol
        2. Second field add the DISTRIBUTION account PUBLIC Key
    6. Amount you are selling: Amount to sell
```

Answer (score 0):

On the testnet, you can [**use stellar laboratory to create an account and fund it using friendbot**](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#account-creator?network=test) as well.

On the pubnet, you can "withdraw" money from an exchange to a public key that you control and the exchange will automatically create the stellar account for you.

**Make sure that you store your secret key safely**

Answer (score 0):

Just as the documentation clearly mentions,

> To create a test account, send Friendbot the public key you created. It’ll create and fund a new account using that public key as the account ID.

- Create your own public key use ED25519 public-key signature system
- Perform a GET to the request friendlybot -`https://friendbot.stellar.org/?addr=`